# Approximate estimation or evaluation to find the answer of the limit

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, infinity

As the title suggests, how can I find the answer of this limit?
I do not know exactly about what kind of this problem belongs to, maybe estimation or evaluation.
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n \left[(\dfrac 1 {\pi} \sum_{k=1}^n \sin\dfrac{\pi} {\sqrt{n^2+k}})^n - \dfrac 1 {\sqrt[4]{e}}\right]$$

Minutes passed; I find the core of the limit (in the parentheses) equals to the following formula
$$1 - \dfrac 1 {4n} + (\dfrac {\pi^2} 6 - \dfrac 1 8)\dfrac 1 {n^2} + o(\dfrac 1 {n^2})$$

Could someone give hints on how I would go about the next step?
Thank you very much.

Comment: So you are looking for the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot [1 -\frac 1{4n} + \ldots]$?

Comment: Then you can find that the quantity inside the $[\ \ ]$ is bounded away from $0$ once $n$ is large enough and the limit is $+\infty$

Comment: $$\Big(1 - \dfrac 1 {4n} + (\dfrac {\pi^2} 6 - \dfrac 1 8)\dfrac 1 {n^2} + o(\dfrac 1 {n^2})\Big)^n=e^{n\ln\Big(1 - \dfrac 1 {4n} + (\dfrac {\pi^2} 6 - \dfrac 1 8)\dfrac 1 {n^2} + o(\dfrac 1 {n^2})\Big)}$$
$$\ln(1+\alpha)=\alpha-\frac{\alpha^2}2+\frac{\alpha^3}3_....$$

Comment: Oh maybe it's $$\dfrac 1 {\sqrt[4]{e}}$$,not $$\dfrac 1 {4\sqrt{e}}$$I got it,thanks